# Angular StrictNullChecks: "Object is possibly 'null' "

Tags: angular, typescript, object, dom, null

My Angular is showing "strictNullChecks" in my project. Now, I have a bunch of errors like this in templates (.html):

```
      <input
        #inputValue
        type="text"
        (keyup.enter)="showStyle(inputValue.value)"
      />

    <p id="addStyle" style="color: blue; display: none" #hide>HELLO</p>
```

(.ts):

```
      addingStyle = window.document.getElementById("addStyle") as HTMLParagraphElement;

      showStyle(inputValue: string) { 
        if (inputValue === "help") {
          this.addingStyle.style.display = "block";
          console.log("help");
        } else {
          console.log("it worked");
        }
      }
```

and it's showing an error like this:

`Object is possibly 'null'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-null-checks)

Use non-null assertion operator ! at the end of nullable expression to avoid these kind of error.

**component.ts**

```
 addingStyle = window.document.getElementById("addStyle")! as HTMLParagraphElement;
```

**component.html**

```
 <input
        #inputValue
        type="text"
        (keyup.enter)="showStyle(inputValue!.value)"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this error is for `addingStyle` or `inputValue` but in `tsconfig.json`, you can turn strictNullChecks off:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, I set `strictNullChecks` to false and it worked for me. I will check it and edit my answer ASAP.